# VBA obtain Nasdaq Analyst Price Targets (Need the actual $ to appear in my code) Current Output works but shows $0

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

```vba
Sub Get_Web_Data2(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim price As Variant
    
    
    ' Website to go to
    website = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/" & Target.Value & "/analyst-research"
    
    ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    
    ' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    
    ' Get fresh data.
    request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    
    ' Send the request for the webpage.
    request.send
    
    ' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    
    ' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
    html.body.innerHTML = response
    
    ' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
    price = html.getElementsByClassName("analyst-target-price__description").Item(0).innerText
    
    ' Output the price into a message box.
    
      If Target.Column = 4 Then
            Range("P" & Target.Row).Value = price
           
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: help me understand what "Target.Value" is, from where it is getting value and give a example value.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2,D14,D26,D38,D50,T2,T14,T26,T38,T50")) Is Nothing Then
         Call Get_Web_Data2(Target)
       
       
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Oh target value is me changing the ref cell in my sheet for a ticker symbol. Like D2 would equal NOK or TSLA etc.. when it changes it pulls in the stock info for the price target for that stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is returned from an API call so will not be present in a call to your current URI.

Update to call the API. It returns a small amount of json. Using a json parser seems like overkill so I would go with faster string manipulation.

Values seem to be dollars so format column P as currency with symbol $.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim website As String

    website = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/analyst/" & LCase$(Target.Value) & "/targetprice"
    
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With request
        .Open "GET", website, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        response = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim price As String
    
    price = Left$(Right$(response, Len(response) - (InStr(response, "priceTarget"":") + Len("priceTarget"":") - 1)), InStr(Right$(response, Len(response) - (InStr(response, "priceTarget"":") + Len("priceTarget"":") - 1)), ",") - 1)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Target.column = 4 Then
        Range("P" & Target.row).Value = price
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you looks like it brought in the average price target only. is there a way to pull the whole statement by chance? for example for ticker "NOK" the sentence in the page reads "Based on analysts offering 12 month price targets for NOK in the last 3 months. The average price target is $5.27 with a high estimate of $6 and a low estimate of $3.96627

Comment: You can construct the sentence and extract the high and low in the same way as it is all contained in the response. Duplicate the above used for `price` but insert either `lowPriceTarget` or `highPriceTarget` and concatenate the result (adding in the $ in front of each price as you won't be formatting the column as currency).